# How to index out open and close in pandas datetime dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

Okay so I have a csv with minute data for the S&P 500 index for 2020, and I am looking how to index out only the close and open for 9:30 and 4:00 only. In essence I just want what the market open and close was. So far the code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

d = pd.read_csv('/Volumes/Seagate Portable/usindex_2020_all_tickers_awvbxk9/SPX_2020_2020.txt')
d.columns = ['Dates', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
d.drop(['High', 'Low'], axis=1, inplace=True)
d.set_index('Dates', inplace=True)

d.head()
```

It wont let me share the csv file but this is what the output looks like:

```
                    Open    Close
Dates       
2020-01-02 09:31:00 3247.19 3245.22
2020-01-02 09:32:00 3245.07 3244.66
2020-01-02 09:33:00 3244.89 3247.61
2020-01-02 09:34:00 3247.38 3246.92
2020-01-02 09:35:00 3246.89 3249.09
```

I have tried using loc and dt.time, which I am assmuning is the right way to code I just cannot think of the exact code to index out these 2 times. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If the `.dt` extractor is used on the `'Dates'` column (`d.Dates.dt.time[0]`), the `.time` component is `datetime.time(9, 30)`, therefore `d.Dates.dt.time == dtime(9, 30)` must be used for the `Boolean` match, and not `d.Dates.dt.time == '09:30:00'`

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time as dtime

# test dataframe
d = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['2020-01-02 09:30:00', '2020-01-02 09:31:00', '2020-01-02 09:32:00', '2020-01-02 09:33:00', '2020-01-02 09:34:00', '2020-01-02 09:35:00', '2020-01-02 16:00:00'], 'Open': [3247.19, 3247.19, 3245.07, 3244.89, 3247.38, 3246.89, 3247.19], 'Close': [3245.22, 3245.22, 3244.66, 3247.61, 3246.92, 3249.09, 3245.22]})

# display(d)
                 Dates     Open    Close
0  2020-01-02 09:30:00  3247.19  3245.22
1  2020-01-02 09:31:00  3247.19  3245.22
2  2020-01-02 09:32:00  3245.07  3244.66
3  2020-01-02 09:33:00  3244.89  3247.61
4  2020-01-02 09:34:00  3247.38  3246.92
5  2020-01-02 09:35:00  3246.89  3249.09
6  2020-01-02 16:00:00  3247.19  3245.22

# verify Dates is a datetime format
d.Dates = pd.to_datetime(d.Dates)

# use Boolean selection for 9:30 and 16:00 (4pm)
d = d[(d.Dates.dt.time == dtime(9, 30)) | (d.Dates.dt.time == dtime(16, 0))].copy()

# set the index
d.set_index('Dates', inplace=True)

# display(d)
                        Open    Close
Dates                                
2020-01-02 09:30:00  3247.19  3245.22
2020-01-02 16:00:00  3247.19  3245.22
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked for. To be honest I tried this exact code though my issue was using OR instead of |, thank you again.

Comment: @benito.cano You're welcome. Happy New Year!

Comment: Thank you Happy New year to you as well!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

# create dummy daterange
date_range = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range("00:00", "23:59", freq='1min'))

# create df with enumerated column as data, and with daterange(DatetimeIndex) as index
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[i for i, d in enumerate(date_range)], index=date_range)

# boolean index using strings
four_and_nine = df[(df.index == '16:00:00') | (df.index == '21:00:00')]

print(four_and_nine)

                        0
2021-01-01 16:00:00   960
2021-01-01 21:00:00  1260
```

Pandas is pretty smart with comparing strings to actual datetimes(DatetimeIndex in this case).

Above is selecting top of the hour. If you wanted all minutes/seconds within specific hours, use boolean index like: `df[(df.index.hour == 4) | (df.index.hour == 9)]`

Comment: worked for me. copy/paste my dummy code(updated)

Comment: It seems that if the time series is created with `pd.date_range` then `== '16:00:00'` works as a `Boolean` selection. However, if the `Dates` column is created as shown in my sample or if it's imported from a csv, and the `Dates` column is converted to a datetime dtype, then `== datetime.time(16, 0)` works, and `== '16:00:00'` does not. It's not clear to me, why this is the case.